# Random javascript images in html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I want to show a random image in a div or an img tag in a html document. I did the same for the title of the page but I can't do it with the image. Does anyone have any idea how I can fix it?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="banner-section" id="img-container"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="foto.js"></script>
  <script src="titulo.js"></script>
</html>
```

JS Title:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var respuesta = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        var cambiar = respuesta.titulos;
        var title = cambiar[Math.floor(Math.random() * cambiar.length)]
        document.title = title.titulo
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "titulos.json", true);
xhttp.send();
```

JS Image:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var respuesta = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        var cambiar = respuesta.fotos;
        var title = cambiar[Math.floor(Math.random() * cambiar.length)]
        document.getElementById("img-container") = title.foto
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "imagenes.json", true);
xhttp.send();
```

.JSON Title:

```
{
"titulos" : [
    {"titulo" : "1"},
    {"titulo" : "2"},
    {"titulo" : "3"},
    {"titulo" : "4"}
]
}
```

.JSON Image:

```
{
"fotos" : [
    {"foto" : "/images/1.jpg"},
    {"foto" : "/images/2.jpg"},
    {"foto" : "/images/3.jpg"},
    {"foto" : "/images/4.jpg"}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an image with that src, you can't just assign a string to an html node:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute("src", title.foto);
document.getElementById("img-container").appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the photo link to the backgroundImage property of *img-container*

> How to set background image using JavaScript - [Check this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp)

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var respuesta = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        var cambiar = respuesta.fotos;
        var title = cambiar[Math.floor(Math.random() * cambiar.length)]
        document.getElementById("img-container").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + title.foto + ')';
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "imagenes.json", true);
xhttp.send();
```